# Redimensionamento no iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

[RESOLVIDO] 
Pessoal, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas resolvi o problema refazendo o que eu já sabia que estava errado, esse código era legado, e não estava nada bom, porém por falta de tempo eu precisava apenas dar um jeitinho de funcionar. Negociamos mais tempo com o cliente e agora já está tudo certo.

---

Galera, tenho uma UIView que é instanciada em runtime, tudo ia bem nos iPhones antigos, mas agora no 6 e 6+, essas UIViews não acompanham o tamanho da UIView pai, que tem constraints nas laterais (leading e trailing). Além disso, essas UIViews ficam em uma célula de uma tabela.

O que eu tentei fazer, foi chamar o [self.tableView reloadData] no viewDidLayoutSubviews e no viewDidAppear do UIViewController, resolveu o problema, porém o UIViewController aparece com a view no tamanho antigo e depois se redesenha pro tamanho novo (demora um pouco, então isso fica visível pro usuário)
Tem alguma forma de eu fazer esse redimensionamento sem que seja visível pro usuário?

```
int width = barView.frame.size.width;
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 10)];
            backgroundImageView.image = [backgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 1, 1, 1)];

            [barView addSubview:backgroundImageView];
```

o problema é que quando faço no viewDidLoad, o width é 280, quando faço no viewDidAppear, o width é 374...

Se houver alguma função em que já tenho o tamanho da View porém ela ainda não foi renderizada, seria o ideal pra eu atualizar a tabela...

Comment: Se possível mostre um trecho do seu código que está tendo problema, vai ser mais fácil.

Comment: coloquei um trecho aí, obrigado pelo toque...

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você está usando layout constraints na sua view tree, só achei meio esquisito você usar frame para uma view específica.

Depois de você popular qualquer view (isso inclui `UITable`**View**`Cell`), que tenha variação de tamanho, você precisa chamar dois métodos do UIView para "dizer" ao UIKit para atualizar suas views no screen do device.

1. `setNeedsLayout`: para invalidar o layout atual e atualiza-lo no próximo ciclo, geralmente baseado no *intrinsic size* ou do frame.
2. `layoutIfNeeded`: para atualizar o layout da sua view baseado nos valores atuais.

Já tive um problema parecido e isso resolveu totalmente o meu problema, espero que ajude.

Comment: pois é... era um código legado, eu precisava resolver rápido... porém renegociei com o cliente e refiz da maneira correta, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas nem vou conseguir testar. rs